# Increasing numbers in recursive functions

Tags: c++, recursion

for a programming assignment, I have to load a tree into an array in order.

The recursive algorithm itself is no problem for me. The problem I'm having is keeping the subscript/element numbers increased periodically so that the data goes into the right array element, instead of overwriting each other after calls return.

```
void foo( currentNode, data[], element? )
{
    // base case
    if ( currentNode == NULL )

    foo( currentNode->left, data, element? );
    data[ element++ ] = currentNode->data; // what do I do in between the left and right subtree calls?
    foo( currentNode->right, data, element? );
}
```

So, how do I increase the element so that it only increases to the next spot of the array for an inorder traversal?

Hints are nice, but I wouldn't mind solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your data parameter a reference to a pointer:

```
void foo(Node* currentNode, ContentType*& data) {
  //...
  *data++ = currentNode->data;
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correct, all you need is a pointer

```
void foo( currentNode, data[], int &element )

foo( currentNode->left, data, element );
data[ element++ ] = currentNode->data;
```

with this, you can change the value of element (more precisely the value, element is pointing on) with each call of foo

Comment: It's C++, so use **REFERENCES**, please.

Comment: sorry I'm not very familiar with references, as I'm writing mainly in plain C, but feel free to edit my post

Comment: Ok, edited to make it use a reference. References cannot be set to NULL, can't be deleted and can't be changed to point to another object, so when using references, you don't have to think about those things when dealing with references. Of course you still have to make sure the object you pass as reference will exist for the required time. The only disadvantage of references is that pass-by-reference is not obvious at the call site, you have to remember what are output arguments (it's best to avoid output arguments and use return wherever you can).